# Android: How to change Items created with a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm rebuilding my app design and would like to use a ViewPager for it. The implementation wasn't quite the problem, but I can't figure out how to change my TextViews inside the pages. Hours of googling didn't help me either. Maybe you can help me. I simply need to know how to change the text, textcolor and stuff of my TextViews. 
main.xml includes my ViewPager and speiseplan.xml includes the TextViews inside a ScrollView, each with an id.

main.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/awesomepager" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I won't write the whole speiseplan.xml here, since it simply includes a ScrollView and a bunch of TextViews.

Implementation in Java is the following:

```
public class Speiseplan extends Activity {

    private ViewPager myPager;
private static int NUM_VIEWS = 14;
private MyPagerAdapter myAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    myAdapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
    myPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}

private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return NUM_VIEWS;
        }


        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.speiseplan, null);

            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2){
            ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
        }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

Now how can I access my TextViews and change them. And how can I detect the user sqiping to another page.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to change the TextViews in the `instantiateItem()` method. It works almost like the `getView()` method in other adapters.

The PagerAdapter does not automatically recycle views like other adapters such as BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter. You may want to implement the recycling yourself. Take a look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) which gives some hints about how to do this.

To detect swipe, you can use the [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) interface.

Comment: Somehow I can't get it to work. I just can't acces the TextViews I have defined in my layout. Maybe you could provide me with some sample code?

Comment: Hmm.. You should be able to call 'view.findViewById()' with your TextView ids declared in your xml file. What exactly do you mean by not being able to "access" the TextViews?

Comment: When I call them like you said it, it seems assigning it to a variable works, but I can't change the text or something like I would normally do.

Comment: Strange. Do you do the same as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7018289/236130)? You may also want to change your initialization of the LayoutInflator to something like this: `[...] = LayoutInflator.from(Speiseplan.this)`. I'm not sure it will do anything different, but at least it is a bit simpler than your current way to do it.

Comment: Okay, changing the text inside of the instantiateItem() method now works, thanks a lot. I'll try get it to work somehow.